# git ls-remote fails when logged out

Tags: git, ssh, buildbot

I'm facing a strange problem with the "git ls-remote command".
I get the following error message when I am logged out :

> Permission denied (publickey).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

It appears when I try to use buildbot and I don't know how to solve it.

I managed to simulate the problem with a simple script loop.sh :

```
for i in {1..100}
do
   echo "$i ls-remote"
   git ls-remote git+ssh://git@sourcesup.renater.fr:2222/simol.git
   echo
   sleep 4
done
```

I run this script using screen.
It works when I am logged in:

> 1 ls-remote
> 3d461dd036960bb69a90a4259789bed5dc2741f7        HEAD
> 3d461dd036960bb69a90a4259789bed5dc2741f7        refs/heads/master
>
> 2 ls-remote
> 3d461dd036960bb69a90a4259789bed5dc2741f7        HEAD
> 3d461dd036960bb69a90a4259789bed5dc2741f7        refs/heads/master
>
> 3 ls-remote
> 3d461dd036960bb69a90a4259789bed5dc2741f7        HEAD
> 3d461dd036960bb69a90a4259789bed5dc2741f7        refs/heads/master

Then, I log out... wait for some seconds, and log in again.
The git ls-remote command fails.
In this example, I logged out after the 13th iteration:

> 13 ls-remote
> 3d461dd036960bb69a90a4259789bed5dc2741f7        HEAD
> 3d461dd036960bb69a90a4259789bed5dc2741f7        refs/heads/master
>
> 14 ls-remote
> Permission denied (publickey).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.
>
> 15 ls-remote
> Permission denied (publickey).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is your private key passphrase-protected? Probably, when you log out, your keychain gets locked and denies access to the private key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your help.

I finally found a solution to my problem.
I have to set ForwardAgent to 'no' when I connect with ssh:

```
ssh -o ForwardAgent=no my_buildbot_slave_machine
```

Indeed, by default ForwardAgent is set to "yes" in my ssh configuration. It means that the ssh keys of my own machine are used when I am connected to the slave machine, instead of those of the slave machine. When I disconnect, my own ssh keys are not available anymore and the problem appears.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you aren't starting your buildbot instance with launchd, but with a terminal/ssh connection. There's a helpful [page](http://trac.buildbot.net/wiki/UsingLaunchd) "A buildbot process which is not started through launchd may not work properly. Worse yet, some of these authorities will be available to a process started in an ssh session, but will go away once you log out of that ssh session."